# JHipster 5 : No reactive APIs found in source code

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I actually trying to generate a backend services using the new version 5 (beta) of Jhipster.

**Below my answers for the generator questions :**

```
C:\dev\java\jh>jhipster server
Using JHipster version installed globally
Executing jhipster:server
Options:
? What is the base name of your application? jh
? What is your default Java package name? com.mycompany.myapp
? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with disk-based persistence
? Do you want to use the Spring cache abstraction? Yes, with the Ehcache implementation (local cache, for a single node)
? Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
? Which other technologies would you like to use? Reactive APIs, using Spring Webflux
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
```

Note that I have choosed the **reactive APIs** new feature, when I take a look on the source code at the RestController level i did'nt find any use of **Mono** and **Flux**.

Did I missed something ?

Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have the option when you create a Spring Controller. And you do have the Spring Webflux library in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me a headache.

If anyone is looking for Reactive Jhipster it's currently being re-written.

It was added in [Jhipster@Beta5.0.0](https://www.jhipster.tech/2018/04/03/jhipster-release-5.0.0-beta.0.html)

**Reactive support**

```
"New generator option to enable Spring Webflux support
Support for Spring Webflux in the Spring controller sub-generator"
```

**It was later removed in** [Jhipster@Beta.5.0.1](https://www.jhipster.tech/2018/05/03/jhipster-release-5.0.0-beta.1.html)

```
We removed our reactive support in Spring Boot. This is going to be 
completely re-written in a separate branch, and will be released later. 
Reactive applications will be a new type of application (like we 
already have monolith or microservice), which will be used only when 
this technology makes sense.
```

Also, active development (within the past day) on [this branch](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/reactive)